# Restriction of an ultrafilter.

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra, filters

Thinking about ultrafilters a question came to my mind. Suppose that we have $A$ and $B$ two Boolean algebras such that $A\subseteq B$ and $U$ be an ultrafilter composed by elements of $B$. Is it true that $U\cap A$ is an ultrafilter on $A$?

Clearly $U\cap A$ is a filter on $A$. Only remains to prove the maximality. For this I cannot prove it but I tried:

Suppose $U\cap A$ is not an ultrafilter on $A$. Then there exist $\mathcal{F}$ an ultrafilter on $A$ such that $U\cap A\subsetneq \mathcal{F}$ (proper contention). Then there exist $F\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $F\notin U\cap A$. But then $F\notin U$. From here I don't know how to continue. I think that we can use $F$ to construct a new filter that contains $U$ and $F$ to derive a contradiction with the maximality of $U$ in $B$. Any hint?

Comment: I made a mistake writing the hypotheses. I have already corrected it.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ is a sub Boolean algebra of $B$?  (As opposed to, say, a sublattice of $B$ which happens to be also a Boolean algebra, but with possibly not inherited interpretations of $\top$, $\bot$, $\lnot$?)

Comment: In this case, $A$ and $B$ are Boolean subagebras of $B(X)$ (the clopen sets of $X$ and here $X$ is $T_2$ and zero-dimensional viewed as a Boolean algebra with $\cup, \cap$ and the usual complement of sets).

Comment: More generally, if $f : A \to B$ is a morphism of Boolean algebras and $U$ is an ultrafilter of $B$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is an ultrafilter of $A$.  This is the special case where $f$ is an inclusion map.  (Thus, for example if $g : X \to Y$ is a map of sets, then you get a morphism of Boolean algebras $g^* : P(Y) \to P(X)$ and from that you get a way to "push forward" an ultrafilter on $X$ to an ultrafilter on $Y$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct.  Consider the filter on $B$ generated by $U\cup\{F\}$.  This will be a proper filter as long as there is no finite subset of $U\cup\{F\}$ whose meet is $0$.  Since $U$ is closed under finite meets, this can only happen if some element $u\in U$ is disjoint from $F$.  But then $u\leq \neg F$ so $\neg F\in U$.  But $\neg F\in A$ so $\neg F\in U\cap A\subseteq\mathcal{F}$, which is a contradiction since $F\in\mathcal{F}$.

Or more simply: a filter is an ultrafilter iff for any $a$, exactly one of $a$ and $\neg a$ is in the filter.  It is then trivial that if $U$ satisfies this condition as a filter on $B$, then $U\cap A$ satisfies it as a filter on $A$.  (More generally, this characterization is typically the "right" way to think about ultrafilters; the fact that it is equivalent to being a maximal proper filter is somewhat of a coincidence.)